# Expanding a template in an other templates' block

Tags: django, django-templates

I have to do a little websites rendering a few pages with static content.

The pages are based on a `base.html` template, this template has a `content` block.

The pages may have (or not) an `aside` element (always the same aside).

Thus far I can do something like this :

**page.html :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% include "page-content.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**page-content.html :**

```
{% extends "content-with[out]-aside.html" %}

{% block content %}
foo
{% endblock %}
```

**content-with-aside.html :**

```
<div>
  <div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <aside>
    aside
  <aside>
</div>
```

**content-without-aside.html :**

```
<div>
  <div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

But that supposes using a template with no usefulness but defining if the page has or not the aside.

I could also define a `base-with-aside.html` and a `base-without-aside.html` templates. But could I do something like this?

**page.html :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% expandblock "content-with[out]-aside.html" %}
{% block content %}
foo
{% endblock %}
{% endexpandblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

In Jinja perhaps?

At worst case I could define a custom template tag, but I would like to know it there already is a feature like this.

Comment: in page-content.html, you use `expande` instead of `expands`, typo?

Comment: @jrbedard Yes, my bad. I just fixed it.